# Calling COBOL/DB2 subprog from COBOL mainprog returns a CEE3204S error from compile unit of subprog

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe

I'm trying to call a COBOL/DB2 subprog from COBOL mainprog. But when run, it returns this error:

```
CEE3204S The system detected a protection exception (System Completion Code=0C4).
From compile unit ABCDBQUE...
```

Here's how I called the subprog from mainprog:

```
       01  WS-HOST-VARIABLES.
           05 WS-ACCT-NO.
              10 WS-REGN-CODE            PIC X(04).
              10 WS-BRANCH-CODE          PIC X(04).
              10 WS-ACCOUNT-NO           PIC X(08).
           05 WS-HOST-ACCT-NO            PIC X(16).
           05 WS-ACCT-STATUS.
              10 WS-DORMANT-STATUS       PIC X(03) VALUE '002'.
              10 WS-CLOSED-STATUS        PIC X(03) VALUE '004'.
       01  WS-DB-QUERY                   PIC X(20).
       01  WS-DB-QUERY-STATUS            PIC X(01).
           88 DB-QUERY-SUCCEEDED         VALUE 'S'.
           88 DB-QUERY-FAILED            VALUE 'F'.
..........
       01  WS-PRT-LINE3.
           05 FILLER                     PIC X(10) VALUE ' REGION:  '.
           05 WS-PRT-REGION-NAME         PIC X(70).
       01  WS-PRT-LINE4.
           05 FILLER                     PIC X(10) VALUE ' BRANCH:  '.
           05 WS-PRT-BRANCH-NAME         PIC X(70).
..........
       0810-GET-REGION-AND-BRANCH.
           MOVE 'GET REGION BRANCH' TO WS-DB-QUERY
           CALL 'ABCDBQUE' USING WS-DB-QUERY
                                 WS-DB-QUERY-STATUS 
                                 WS-REGN-CODE 
                                 WS-BRANCH-CODE 
                                 WS-ACCOUNT-NO 
                                 WS-PRT-REGION-NAME
                                 WS-PRT-BRANCH-NAME.
           EVALUATE TRUE 
               WHEN DB-QUERY-SUCCEEDED
                    DISPLAY 'GET REGION BRANCH SUCCEEDED'
               WHEN DB-QUERY-FAILED
                    DISPLAY 'GET REGION BRANCH FAILED'
           END-EVALUATE.
```

Here's what my subprog looks like:

```
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
............
      *
       LINKAGE SECTION. 
       01  LS-DB-QUERY                   PIC X(20).
           88 DB-SELECT-ACCT             VALUE 'INQUIRE DEPTABLE'.
           88 DB-SELECT-REG-BRANCH       VALUE 'GET REGION BRANCH'.
           88 DB-UPDATE                  VALUE 'ACCT STATUS UPDATE'.
       01  LS-DB-QUERY-STATUS            PIC X(01).
           88 DB-QUERY-SUCCEEDED         VALUE 'S'.
           88 DB-QUERY-FAILED            VALUE 'F'.
       01  LS-ACCT-NO.
           05 LS-REGN-CODE               PIC X(04).
           05 LS-BRANCH-CODE             PIC X(04).
           05 LS-ACCOUNT-NO              PIC X(08).
       01  LS-PRT-REGION-NAME            PIC X(70).
       01  LS-PRT-BRANCH-NAME            PIC X(70).
      *
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LS-DB-QUERY, 
                                LS-DB-QUERY-STATUS,
                                LS-ACCT-NO,
                                LS-PRT-REGION-NAME,
                                LS-PRT-BRANCH-NAME.
..........
```

Return code from compiling both programs are all 0. When I didn't separate the subprog from mainprog, it works successfully. But fails when I started to add this Static Calling feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `CALL` you are passing 7 parameters, but you are only `USING`  5 - that won't work. The parameter-lists in the calling and called program must be exact matches.

Comment: Thanks. When running the COBOL mainprog, should I use a jcl that runs COBOL/DB2 program since the subprog is COBOL/db2 or running it with a JCL running COBOL program is enough?

Comment: You have to use a JCL with DB2, otherwise the connection won't be established.

Comment: I compiled both mainprog(COBOL) subprog(COBOL/DB2) using cobol/db2 compiler, binded both as well, then ran the mainprog using JCL with DB2. Return code is 0, but based on my output file, running the mainprog didn't seem to be able to call the subprog. Did I do something wrong in compiling/bind/run process?

Comment: I think that answer as-is is not correct.
COBOL commonly allows "extra" arguments - they will just be unused, won't they?
The issue I see is that the parameters doesn't match, I think it should work as soon as `WS-REGN-CODE WS-BRANCH-CODE ACCOUNT-NO` are replaced by `WS-ACCT-NO`, even when more parameters are added at the end.